# How do I submit a contact form in mail using php?

Tags: php

hey i wanted my contact from to submit to my cpanel mail id i tried a lot of codes but its not working the only code that working is

```
<?php

$sender = 'bla@example.ae';
$recipient = 'bla@example.ae';

$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "You have received a new message from the user $name." .
    "Here is the message:\n $message" .
    "Here is the mail:\n $email" .
    $headers = 'From:' . $sender;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message)) {
    echo "Message accepted";
} else {
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
```

this but its only mailing the message not the others it would be nice if anyone would msg the PHP code to submit the form

Answer (score 0):

> but its only mailing the message not the others

Did you mean the email body you got contains the words ("*You have received ...*") except the `name`, `message`, and `email` parts were blank?

That's probably due to the sequence of your variable declarations and references. You must declare your variables (ie, assign values to them) first before you can reference them (ie, use them in the `$message`).

For example:

```
<?php

$recipient = 'bla@example.ae';
$subject = "php mail test";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$sender = 'bla@example.ae';
// I'm assuming you're going to validate, sanitize, and escape $name, $email, and $message
$message = "You have received a new message from the user {$name}.\n" .
    "Here is the mail:\n {$email}\n" .
    "Here is the message:\n {$message}";
$headers = "From: $sender";

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "Message accepted";
} else {
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
```